# Calling a stored proc via SSMS command and passing strings with spaces

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm wondering if anyone has an example of calling a stored proc via an SSMS command and passing in string parameters where the string values contain spaces?

Example of proc header that I'm interested in passing string values to:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.P427007ImportAHSAHospitalDetails
    @Path       VARCHAR(255),
    @FileName   VARCHAR(255),
    @OperatorID VARCHAR(10),
    @BranchID   VARCHAR(10),
    @TillID     VARCHAR(10)
AS 
BEGIN

    SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
    SET ANSI_PADDING ON
    {etc}
```

Comment: Please post your code where you are trying to do this so we can see where you are going wrong.

Comment: *"I'm wondering if anyone has an example of calling a stored proc"* Yes, it's called the documentation. [SQL Server technical documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/?view=sql-server-ver15). A lot of the pages contain examples, as well as an explanation.

Comment: It is a Monday morning ...  sorry, an average question ... time for a coffee ..

Comment: What do spaces have to do with anything now? Your answer doesn't have any strings with spaces, and why would have a space in a literal string change the behaviour?

Comment: Was just reminding myself that the parameters are a comma separated list of values and not space separated .. and to put string parameters in single quotes ..   Date parameters are covered in other stackoverflow questions ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I have worked this out now ..

e.g. example call as per:

```
exec [dbo].[P427007ImportAHSAHospitalDetails] @Path='\\SHD-D-EDIAPP01\H2FileRepository\DEV\CommonDev\Import Files\Provider Import\', @FileName='HospitalDetails-0005-20180529.XML', @OperatorID='hslafo', @BranchID='HO', @TillID='HOBO'
```

Stored proc is as per:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.P427007ImportAHSAHospitalDetails
    @Path       VARCHAR(255),
    @FileName   VARCHAR(255),
    @OperatorID VARCHAR(10),
    @BranchID   VARCHAR(10),
    @TillID     VARCHAR(10)
AS 
BEGIN

    SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
    SET ANSI_PADDING ON
    {etc}
```

Comment: If all your parameters are a `varchar` (seems an odd choice for an "ID"), then why are you passing `nvarchar` literal strings? If the strings are an `nvarchar`, and therefore your columns (I assume), then your parameters should be too.

Comment: Good point ..  changed call to:    exec [dbo].[P427007ImportAHSAHospitalDetails] @Path='\\SHD-D-EDIAPP01\H2FileRepository\DEV\CommonDev\Import Files\Provider Import', @FileName='HospitalDetails-0005-20180529.XML', @OperatorID='hslafo', @BranchID='HO', @TillID='HOBO'